# Harry Potter Half-Blood Prince fiasco

Tags: single-word-requests

> "If I'm having lessons with you, I won't have to do Occlumency lessons
>   with Snape, will I." ''Professor Snape, Harry — and no, you will not."
>   "Good," said Harry in relief, "because they were a —" He stopped,
>   careful not to say what he really thought.
>
> "I think the word 'fiasco' would be a good one here," said Dumbledore,
>   nodding.

In that excerpt, Dumbledore replaces a word Harry has not said with 'fiasco'. Not being a native speaker myself, however, I've been wondering: what's the word that Harry would have said, had he not considered it inappropriate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to know the correct answer. However, it would probably be a similar word to fiasco, only more negative and derogatory towards Snape. Perhaps "waste of time," "awful," or "catastrophe." But again, there's no way to know.

Comment: Thanks! In that case, however, I wonder: why not say any of these, these words/expressions don't seem that terrible to me, especially since Dumbledore always knew how much Harry loathed Snape. I always thought it's a swear word :D

Comment: It might even have been 'fiasco'.

Comment: @cindi: I'm not sure about your 'hesitate to disrespect' since immediately before Harry didn't use Snape's title and was corrected for the disrespect (even though leaving the title is a pretty automatic, unconscious thing).

Answer (score 1):

Considering that Harry was impolitely leaving out Snape's "professor"-title, he probably wanted to finish the sentence with a rude word or even a swear word.

The only way to know what Harry really wanted to say is to ask the author, I suppose.